# monotouch NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, nskeyedarchiver

does anyone have any examples of using NSKeyedArchiver in monotouch? i just want to store a list of pocos

w://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there are NSKeyedArchiver examples for MonoTouch but, if you are looking for a how to persist objects via serialization, you can use the .Net serialization APIs in MonoTouch and use C# examples.

As for using the NSKeyedArchiver stuff, it has been bound and is available so you might want to try use an Objective-C example as a guide for doing it in MonoTouch.

Comment: using .net serialization sounds like a better approach :)